# What kind of prediction/ classification is this?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models

Suppose I have a data frame like the following (and I want to do machine learning):

```
|--------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|  
|person(race)  |  Apple    |  Orange   |  Banana   |   Peach   |...    
|Jack (white)  |    10     |    9      |   24      |    65     |   
|Jenna (white) |    9      |    67     |   94      |    37     |  
|Emily (asian) |    10     |    0      |    4      |    25     |   
|Sophia (asian)|    23     |    65     |   74      |    65     |   
|John (black)  |    0      |    34     |    0      |    65     |  
|Chen (asian)  |    86     |    77     |   90      |     0     |
       ...
|--------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

if my question is: Does Emily like orange? if yes, how much?

1. What kind of prediction would this be? Is it some type of classification where Emily is asian so the chance of loving orange is $x$? Or is this a linear regression problem?
2. What kind of prediction model should I use? random forest, KNN...etc?

Comment: You might look into "recommender systems," which attempt to predict one's preferences about individual items in circumstances like these. To clarify, what do the numbers represent? The number of each fruit that each individual has consumed? Preference each individual has assigned to each fruit?

Comment: they are random numbers that i made up haha, so yes! you can think of those number as  "The number of each fruit that each individual has consumed". And what I mean by "like" is that the value is NOT 0.